# How to get email signature from OWA/Outlook 365 using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I have a problem accessing email signature using EWS (Exchange Web Services) Managed API in C#. So far I wrote this code in my `Main` method:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(mail, password)
};
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.AutodiscoverUrl(mail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

//CertificateValidationCallBack and RedirectionUrlValidationCallback 
//methods are declared in other place;
//I literally took them from Microsoft site

var OWAConfig = UserConfiguration.Bind(service, "OWA.UserOptions", WellKnownFolderName.Root,
    UserConfigurationProperties.All);
```

This code works, but, as I understand, OWAConfig should contain all settings from OWA/Outlook 365 - but it doesn't. The OWAConfig variable has a property called `Dictionary` (as it should), which has 16 entries (eg. entry with key `"ClientTypeOptInState"` and value `2`, entry with key `"IsFocusedInboxEnabled"` with value `true`, etc.). But as far as I can tell it doesn't have what I'm most interested in - the email signature.

How can I access email signature configured in OWA/Outlook 365 settings? Should I change the `Bind` method? Is `"OWA.UserOptions"` the right parameter? Does it not have the signature? Or maybe it does, but I just can't find it? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of the new https://office365itpros.com/2020/05/18/roaming-signatures-outlook-for-windows/ feature the signature does not get stored in that configuration item anymore. Currently Microsoft hasn't released an API to manage this signature data if you look at what OWA is doing with something like fiddler it calls PATCH https://outlook.office.com/ows/beta/OutlookCloudSettings/settings so it maybe a little bit of time before this becomes a production API that third parties can use.

Comment: But where are these signatures physically stored? I cannot find anything browsing the online store in OutlookSpy/MFCMAPI... Is that data not in the mailbox?

Comment: I'm not sure but "\ApplicationDataRoot\49499048-0129-47f5-b95e-f9d315b861a6\OutlookAccountCloudSettings","Modified","Messages",,"SDS.49499048-0129-47f5-b95e-f9d315b861a6.RoamingSetting" is what i see get modified

Comment: Actually on second look its \ApplicationDataRoot\49499048-0129-47f5-b95e-f9d315b861a6\OutlookAccountCloudSettings then there is a folder for the name of your signature (base64 encoded) then two  "SDS.49499048-0129-47f5-b95e-f9d315b861a6.RoamingSetting items one with the Text Sig and one for the html sig with the data stored in the rawJson http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{2842957E-8ED9-439B-99B5-F681924BD972}/RawJSON/0x0000001F prop

Comment: Yep, that is what I see too - there are a "Roaming_Signature_List" message, and "Roaming_New_Signature" / "Roaming_Reply_Signature" messages and a base-64 encoded child folders with text and html signatures. Not sure why the signature names were base-64 encoded instead of just using the signature names for subfolders...